# Correct way of simplifying the result of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, simplifying-expressions, syntax, integral-transforms

Many times *Mathematica* gives enormous results to simple problems. One uses the program more for trouble than for not knowing how to solve the problem.
As an ejemplo I present this integral that *Mathematica* turns out quickly but with a huge result, even though the attempt to simplify did not reach the result made by hand.

Some ideas please.

[image]

Comment: The question arises: what for? is not it art for art's sake?

Comment: E.g. Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]], {x, -Pi/4, Pi/3}] // FullSimplify performs $$ \frac{\log \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)+\log \left(5-2 \sqrt{6}\right)-2 \log \left(2-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}.$$ Is not it enough simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Many times Mathematica gives enormous results to simple problems

If `Simplify` still does not help reduce the antiderivative to what you like, you could always try [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/downloadRubi.html)

```
<< Rubi`
 integrand = 1/Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]];
 sol = Int[integrand, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 D[sol, x] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a page [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/CAS_integration_tests/index.htm) which compares different integrators with the size of antiderivatives they give.

Comment: wow , I didn't know that extension, great thanks